# The distribution of roll of a dice $12$ times

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics

What's the distribution of a variable $X$ if $X$ represents the number of times you get outcome $k$ when you roll a dice $12$ times?

I thought that the distribution was a binomial distribution with $n=12$ and $p=\dfrac16$, but it seems to be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\forall{k\in[1\dots6],n\in[0\dots12]}:P_k(X=n)=\frac{\binom{12}{n}\cdot5^{12-n}}{6^{12}}=\binom{12}{n}\cdot\left(\frac16\right)^{n}\cdot\left(\frac56\right)^{12-n}$$

Comment: it would help to point out that this *is* in fact binomial.  $\frac{\binom{12}{n}\cdot 5^{12-n}}{6^{12}} = \binom{12}{n}(\frac{1}{6})^n(\frac{5}{6})^{12-n}$

Comment: @JMoravitz: Good point, thanks!

Comment: If i would want to do a hypothesis testing thatthe outcome 6 comes more often then the other, then i should check if the possibilty function is lower or equal to 0.05(=5% error risk) with X>=4 sinxe the number of times of outcome 6 are 4? @JMoravitz

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry for an late answer. @Barakmanos